# Getting size of files in directory

Tags: bash, shell

i am currently facing problem. I am trying to figure out how to get the size within range of every file in current working directory in bytes so i can work with them later on.

When i use `file_size_bytes=$(du "$file" | cut -f1)` with echo next to it in for loop i am getting size of every file on new line and i can see some files have number 4 and this file has size of 1,3KiB for example another one has 24 but has size of 21,6KiB.. is there any way of how to get the proper size of file?

Comment: Which OS/distribution and version you use? Add output of `alias du`.

Comment: Read the man page for your version of `du` to see how to make it use bytes for the size.